# Synchronized keyword in Thread.sleep implementation

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In Thread.sleep(millis,nanos) implementation, which i took my Android Codebase, the function is defined somewhat like this

```
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos) throws InterruptedException {

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (millis * NANOS_PER_MILLI) + nanos;
        Object lock = currentThread().lock;
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (true) {

                  ///implementation
            }
        }
    }
```

`currentThread()` returns the caller thread and `lock` is an object(new Object()) in `Thread` class.

1. Here suppose one thread is currently executing and i call `sleep()` again from second thread, then wont it change the variables `start` and `duration`, which is still in use by the first thread? Shouldnt the whole function be `synchronized` to prevent this?
2. What sense does it make to choose `lock` as a sync object? Anyway, a single instance of a `Thread` wont be able to call `sleep()` multiple times simultaneously?

Comment: `which i took my Android Codebase`. Can you elaborate what you mean by this? Is this your own implementation? Is this how Android implements it?

Comment: I took it from Thread.java file in Android SDK. Its not my implementation.

Comment: What, if any, other functions in the Andriod SDK also synchronize on the object referenced by `lock`?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, But lock is a different object for each caller Thread.

Comment: @Diffy Can you post the code for `currentThread`?

Comment: @Diffy I am not asking about use in the same method in other threads, but about use in other methods being called to operate on the same thread. For example, the purpose of the synchronized block might be to prevent the Thread from going into a sleep while some other thread is attempting an interrupt or a join on that Thread object.

Comment: @ChetanKinger, thats a native method.

Comment: @Diffy In that case, can you search for other places in the SDK where `lock` is being synchronized?